# Timing out a script portion and allowing the rest to continue

Tags: php, timer, timeout, simplexml

I have a widget that runs on my homepage which is loading xml data from an external source. I want to timeout the xml load after x seconds (lately the other site has been having load issues).  Here is the function I have so far. I can't figure out how to make the timer ineract with the `simplexml_load_file()`.

Am I on the right track? Is there a way to make this work?  Or is there a better way to do this? If this does timeout, I still need the rest of the page to continue loading, so I can't use `set_time_limit()`, because that will end *all* script execution, right?

```
function timer($end) {
    $count = 0;
    while($end > $count) {
        sleep(1);
        $count++;
    }
    return true;
}

$we = simplexml_load_file('http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=44.08920&lon=-70.17250&FcstType=xml');
if(timer(3)) return;
```

Comment: timer(3) will start after simplexml_load_file() finished. depending on the behaviour of simplexml_load_file() sleep will probably executed only after the xml file was downloaded.

Comment: @Spliff, I know, but I wasn't sure how to prevent that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use CURL instead of loading the URL directly...

```
function getXml($url, $timeout = 0){
  $ch = curl_init($url);

  curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => (int) $timeout
  ));

  if($xml = curl_exec($ch)){
    return new SimpleXmlElement($xml);
  }
  else {
    return null;
  }
}

//Example
$xmlData = getXml('http://yoururl.com', 2); // 2 second timeout
```

Comment: Actually they were not incorrect. I never use the simple xml functions (other than `simplexml_ import_ dom`) i always use the object directly. Thats a style preference thing. `new SimpleXmlElement` should works just like `simplexml_load_string`. Secondly i also prefer to return null instead of false. So its not a matter of correct/incorrect its a matter of preference :-)

Comment: @JakeParis Your comment is unhelpful as you do not have an answer below or anywhere. This answer didn't work for me.

Answer (score 4):

So you want to set a timeout for `simplexml_load_file()`. You can't set it specifically, but you can just set it globally (for all socket based streams) before using the function:

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 3);
$we = simplexml_load_file($url);

// you can restore the default value after use, if you want
ini_restore('default_socket_timeout');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could first read the content of the file with some blocking or more reliable function (like fopen, fsockopen or curl, choose the best you can use) and then pass the content to **simplexml_load_string** instead of **simplexml_load_file**